# How do I simulate mouse hover with imacros?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, imacros, mousehover

Is there any way to simulate mouse hover with the free edition imacros?

There are some element I want to click that only appear with mouse hovered over.

Answer (score 9):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=HREF:http://*.jpg CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER
```

Comment: This IS the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Chrome browser, you can force a hover state on an element by right-clicking the HTML of the element in Chrome's inspector.